# How to center equally spaced anchor tags in <nav> element of HTML 5

Tags: css, html

I have a couple of basic CSS and HTML5 related questions.

Please bear the ignorance.

I have a `<nav>` element.

```
<nav>
    <a href="/html/">HTML</a>
    <a href="/css/">CSS</a>
    <a href="/js/">JavaScript</a>
    <a href="/jquery/">jQuery</a>
</nav>
```

I want to make the `<a>` tags within the  to be horizontally center aligned .

But `<nav>` is a block level element .

**1> So how does the style work ? It should not work on block level elements right ?**

```
    nav {
        text-align: center;
        border: 1px solid #ABABAB;
    }
```

Also , I want the `anchor tags to be equally spaced and at the same time text within them to be horizontally center aligned` ?

I tried

```
    nav a {
        display: inline-block;
        width:25%;
        border: 1px solid red;
    }
```

But it did not work ?

[image]

**2> How to do this ?**

Please provide an explanation which is easy for a newbie to be understood.

Comment: Is the result you are looking for the image you added?

Comment: @WhiteHox Yes. I do not want to give a fixed width . So how to achieve the same ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use css3 [`flexbox`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). Following css will create the result that you need.

```
nav {
  display: flex;
}
nav a {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```css
nav {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #ABABAB;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: flex;
}
nav a {
  flex-grow: 1;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="/html/">HTML</a>
  <a href="/css/">CSS</a>
  <a href="/js/">JavaScript</a>
  <a href="/jquery/">jQuery</a>
</nav>
<nav>
  <a href="/html/">HTML</a>
  <a href="/css/">CSS</a>
  <a href="/js/">JavaScript</a>
  <a href="/jquery/">jQuery</a>
  <a href="/jquery/">AngularJS</a>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can float the links to the left and clear the `:after` `:before`

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
nav {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #ABABAB;
}
nav a {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
nav:after,
nav:before {
  display: table;
  clear: both;
  content: ' ';
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="/html/">HTML</a>
  <a href="/css/">CSS</a>
  <a href="/js/">JavaScript</a>
  <a href="/jquery/">jQuery</a>
</nav>
```